# Firebase security rules: restrict write only to this uid, except for a couple of fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In Firebase I have a `users` "node", which looks like:

```
users: {
  someUid: {
    username: 'someUsername'
    activeConversations: {},
    profile_picture: ''
    ... lots of other children
  },
  ...
},
anotherNode: {

},
... hundreds of other nodes
```

My rules right now:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": [
        "username"
      ]
    },
    "friendRequests": {
      ".indexOn": [
        "timeSent"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is restrict child's access in the `users` "node" only to the client who owns the child. So for instance, the `someUid` child should only be writeable by the client with uid `someUid`. Other "node" like `anotherNode` can be writeable / readable by any logged-in client.
Also, any logged-in client should be able to write on `profile_picture` and `activeConversations` in the `users` doc.

How can I achieve that without having to put a read/write rule on every single node?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think @Bradley Mackey was nearly there but just needed a small tweak.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["username"],
      // wildcard, matches any node under 'users'
      "$someUid": {
        "$other" : {
          ".read": "($other == 'profile_picture' || $other == 'activeConversations') || auth.uid == $someUid", 
          ".write": "($other == 'profile_picture' || $other == 'activeConversations') || auth.uid == $someUid", 
        }
      }
    },
    "$anythingelse": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
    }
  }
}
```

The `".validate":` field ensures that a field matches a certain format. The read and write here should give everyone read and write access if the field is profile_picture or activeConversations, and give the user access to everything else.

EDIT:

I added in another rule that would allow read-write access to any signed in user to any of the non-users nodes.

Comment: hi Adam. Thanks. What about the other nodes beside `users` however? By default there's no read/write access if not set. The other nodes at the same level of `users` should have read/write access.

Comment: Edited now to hopefully do what you want it to.

Comment: Good answer.  Needs a comma before `"$anythingelse"`

Comment: Thanks Bob, added that in

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work, I am not sure where the pitfall is right now and I'm investigating if it comes from my own data, for instance if fields other than `profile_picture` and `activeConversations` need a write/read access. Will get back here as soon as I delve more into it.

Comment: this does not work, if you have other nodes example if you have a node called `location` it wont work

Answer (score 4):

Having `".read": true, ".write": true` at the root of your database is a **very bad** idea. Literally anyone could just wipe your entire database or insert any data at any time. This is because `.read` and `.write` rules cascade, so if you have them evaluating to `true` at some node, the person has permission for **all children of that node as well.**

Luckily more secure rules, like the rules you are proposing, are easy to implement. I'm assuming that `someUid` is equal to the users `auth.uid` you can do:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["username"],
      // wildcard, matches any node under 'users'
      "$someUid": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write":"auth != null",
        "$other" : {
          ".validate": "($other == 'profile_picture' || $other == 'activeConversations') || auth.uid == $someUid" // only that own user can change their username
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've omitted your `friendRequests` node, because I'm not sure what security rules you'd like for that, but I hope this is enough to get you started.

The [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) cover this stuff very well.

Comment: Thanks for that Bradley. How can I keep the write access to any authenticated user for `activeConversations` and `profile_picture`?

Comment: Also for `friendRequests` and other nodes, we can keep to `write: true` and `read: true`. If we put it in global scope will it cascade down for all nodes (and when setting it for example in `users` then it would override those)?

Comment: @DanP. see my updated answer, also don't set them to `true` unless you very explicitly need it. It's very bad practice, at least check for `auth != null`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have like 50 children besides username, profile_picture etc. Is it possible to set the default to `auth != null && auth.uid == $someUid`, and  set `profile_picture` and `activeConversations` to `auth != null`? (basically switch the rule you wrote under `username` with the rule in `$other`)

Comment: @DanP. yes you can easily do that!

Comment: Hey @Bradley Mackey, I updated the post with what my rules look like now. Does it look like something could be wrong? I added some questions within the code.

Comment: One error I'm getting: `FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/WKLiK2XPdpaYzJtedEZkte0K9qz1 failed: permission_denied` However I am logged-in as this user.

Comment: @DanP. See my updated answer, I've also changed it so it will fully work with the structure you described in a previous comment, so just copy and paste what I've done.

Comment: Using that now and the problem is that I can't write to other nodes, for example I can't write inside `friendRequests`

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, every node should have read and write access for any logged-in user. The only node that needs that different (for the write part only) is the `users` node, which its children should be writeable only by the logged-in user EXCEPT for its children `profile_picture` and `activeConversations`, which should both be available for read/write by any logged-in user.

Comment: Hi Brad, any idea about this? Still haven't gotten around this :/

Comment: Hi sorry, use pastebin or similar so I can have a look at your code.

Comment: I am not sure where the pitfall is right now and I'm investigating if it comes from my own data, for instance if fields other than `profile_picture` and `activeConversations` need a write/read access. Will get back here as soon as I delve more into it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the firebase documentation, you can restrict the access permission at user level and data level

For example,

```
    // These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
    // user's ID from the Firebase auth token
    {
      "rules": {
        "users": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Also you can restrict the read write permission in data level,

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$message": {
        // only messages from the last ten minutes can be read
        ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)",

        // new messages must have a string content and a number timestamp
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['content', 'timestamp']) && newData.child('content').isString() && newData.child('timestamp').isNumber()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Go through these firebase official documentation,
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data